# Components folder or screens folder?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have been learning RN for the past 2 weeks and I had the following question: why would you have a component file and a screen file in the SRC folder? Aren't they the same thing?  I have seen programmers just use a Screens folder where they included all the components into those screens. I have also seen programmers just have a components folder where all the code for screens is going into them. Does it really matter?  What is your preference? The project I am currently working on only has a screens folder.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why people down voted this question, but for me this question really helped, thanks for asking this question here.

Answer (score 2):

In React Native, you would typically use `screens/` folder and create all your component screens in there. Now if you are looking to create reusable components then you could create a `components/` folder and place those particular components in there.

As was stated in the last answer there are no hard and fast rules about this, just convention.

So a good use case is maybe you want to have a UI that shows some cards with content to its users. You may have a `screens/ImageScreen.js` which represents the overall layout in which those Card items will sit, but then for each individual Card item that the user will scroll through inside that screen, it could be an individual component called `Card.js` or `ImageDetail.js` or whatever you wish, which sits inside of a `components/` folder.

So then in your main layout or screen you would import the child into the parent, for example:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import ImageDetail from "../components/ImageDetail";
```

And then you can display that child component inside the parent screen like so:

```
const ImageScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <ImageDetail />
      <ImageDetail />
      <ImageDetail />
      <ImageDetail />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Then you can pass props from that parent screen to the child component to customize how this child component displays itself and shows itself to a user.